# How to validate model field using validator method in Django REST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to validate email while saving an object through API. 
I'm using model validate but it's not working while saving Invitation object through API, It's working only when we creating objects through the admin panel.

models.py

```
def validate_email(value): 
    if "@gmail.com" in value: 
        return value 
    else: 
        raise ValidationError("This field accepts mail id of google only") 


class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(validators=[validate_email])
```

Comment: it's working on my machine. I tested with the help of DRF.

Comment: When i saving object through API not working

Comment: Its working only on when we are saving objects through admin

Answer (score 0):

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) says:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form

and the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework) says:

> With REST framework the validation is performed entirely on the serializer class

Which means in order to validate a model instance creation via api, you will need to define all validations in the Serializer class tself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate it through [`Model.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Answer (score 0):

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

Use serializers to validate model properties.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class Invitation(serializers.Serializer):
    email = models.EmailField()


    def validate_email(self, value):
        if "@gmail.com" in value: 
            return value 
        else: 
            raise ValidationError("This field accepts mail id of google only")
```